# How to remove the "installed manually" flag and revert to "automatically installed" with apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

To compile something, I needed the `zlib1g-dev` package to be installed so I launched an `apt-get install zlib1g-dev`.

`apt-get` informed me nicely that the package was already auto-installed because of an other package, and that it understands that I want it installed explicitly now :

```
# apt-get install zlib1g-dev
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version.
zlib1g-dev set to manually installed.
```

My compilation done, I don't need it any more explicitly, so I want to revert its status to the previous one : auto-installed. This way it will be pruned automatically when it will not be needed any more with a simple `apt-get autoremove`.

I cannot do an `apt-get remove zlib1g-dev` since some packages still depends on it.

**So how may I revert the package `zlib1g-dev`installation state to *auto-installed*** ?

I know that I might edit `/var/lib/apt/extended_states` by hand from

```
Package: zlib1g-dev
Auto-Installed: 0
```

to

```
Package: zlib1g-dev
Auto-Installed: 1
```

... but it just doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Aptitude can help you when you initially install the package:

```
aptitude install "zlib1g-dev&M"
```

Or, after your have installed the package:

```
aptitude markauto "zlib1g"
```

**Edit:** If you do not have aptitude, you can use

```
apt-mark auto zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: Good answer, but I +1's @ArvindSing's answer using `apt-mark` because it does not require that you install `aptitude`. `apt-mark` comes with `apt` package which everyone should already have.

Comment: Worked for me.  Nevertheless I had to use "sudo", at least with the command I issued which was "aptitude markauto ...".

Answer (score 157):

apt-mark can help you:

```
apt-mark auto zlib1g-dev
```

For 11.04 or older, use "apt-get markauto" instead of "apt-mark auto"

Answer (score 11):

This is what you're looking for.

```
sudo apt-get markauto first-package second-package etc-package
```

Source:

```
apt-get --help
```

Comment: Please note that this is deprecated now in favor of apt-mark